# Rows missing while reading a file that was unloaded from Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

I unloaded a set of 200 million records from Redshift to S3 using SQLWorkbench. I got a message saying "Unload complete, 2,00,00,00,000 records complete". However, when I download this file from s3 and open it, there are only 40 million rows. No errors at any point of time. I am very confused and unable to proceed because of this issue.

What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unload of this size will not be in 1 file.  Each unloaded file is limited to 6.2GB or smaller if the MAXFILESIZE parameter is set.  Also, if PARALLEL is ON (default) each slice in Redshift will make its own set of files in S3.  I expect you are only look at one of many files that were created by the UNLOAD.  Each file will have a slice number and a part number attached to the file base name you provided in the UNLOAD statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Actually, I had added PARALLEL OFF, but the file is 6.2GB. There were files with csv001,csv002,...csv008. Thanks alot for this answer again!